# Getting Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException for eventhub triggers

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub, azure-webjobssdk

I am using azure webjobs v3 for eventhub trigger. Till sometime everything was working fine. Suddenly I am getting below error. Can someone help me in resolving this?

```
public async Task Trigger00([EventHubTrigger("%eventhub-00%", Connection = "ConnectionString")] string message)
       {
          blah... 
       }
```

```
Host.Startup[0]
      The listener for function 'Trigger00' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Trigger00' was unable to start. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubsException..ctor(Boolean, System.String, System.Exception)'.
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.EventProcessorConfigurationException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.GetPartitionIdsAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.GetPartitionIdsAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.InitializeStoresAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.StartAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.EventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(IEventProcessorFactory factory, EventProcessorOptions processorOptions)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs\Listeners\EventHubListener.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 68
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 11):

I resolved this by removing my direct dependency on Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs 4.1.0.

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs` 3.0.6 depends on an old version of `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` (**2.1.0**). I have read that there are breaking changes in this package, this might explain the error.

Before:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
```

After:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
```

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the answer ;-) I had the same problem but had the direct reference in a class lib that was used by the function app

Comment: @Zenuka Glad you fixed it. I wasn't the asker :-)

Comment: In my case, my function was dependent on other projects where I was using `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` and I cannot remove it. I downgrade it 3.0

Comment: Can confirm that downgrading to 3.0 fixed our problem too.